# Remove property name from validation message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

Is it possible to remove property name form the validation message? For example, instead of:

> Field **'Name'** should not be empty.

I want to show:

> Field should not be empty.

I need to do this global, for all validators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [localization customization](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Localization&referringTitle=Customising) like so to make the change globally. You can then of course override specific errors with a custom format if you need a one-off change.

```
ValidatorOptions.ResourceProviderType = typeof(MyResources);
```

...

```
public class MyResources {
   public static string notempty_error {
      get { 
          return "Field should not be empty.";
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

easiest way would be to pass a custom message.  You can also override it so it always uses that message.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field should not be Empty")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```